# google plus share and parameters in url

Tags: html, url, google-plus, share

I use Google+ to share some links on my page and there is a problem when I try to share an URL containing parameters. Example:

```
http://google.com?n=somethink&link=p/1393007&i=images/icons/gplus-16.png
```

When you put this URL into the field at this page:

```
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/
```

...and click on the `share` button, you can't see information about page like name, picture and description. But when you delete the dot before "png", then Google shows data about the page.

The same thing happens when you write the `'` symbol anywhere in the URL. I can't find any information about this error in Google Help Pages. It works when I use an URL like this:

```
http://google.com?n='&link=p/1393007&i=images/icons/gplus-16.png
```

...but it isn't very elegant solution.

How to write clean URLs?

Answer (score 41):

currently G+ share supports only two parameters: url, for the target url, and hl, for a language code.

> https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com

Alternatively, you can add OpenGraph tags to the head of your page to specify the same fields like this: (haven't tested yet)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:description" content="..."/>
```

Comment: It's funny you didn't answer their question, but you answered mine!

Comment: Does G+ supports any other additional parameters now?

Comment: @BalasubramaniM, `text` parameter works, but it is not documented, so may be removed in future without notice.

Comment: In my case I have opengraph in meta data still the image is not coming right http://www.126news.com/Publication/Article/how-neuron-works

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you URL encode the link you want to share on Google+ via the Google+ share link.

For example: if you want to share the link `http://example.com?a=b&c=d`, first URL encode the link to look like:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fa%3Db%26c%3Dd
```

Now you can share the link on Google+ through the share link:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fa%3Db%26c%3Dd
```

Comment: I don't think that's necessary> I tried with :// and / , works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
function googleplusbtn(url) {
      sharelink = "https://plus.google.com/share?url="+url;
      newwindow=window.open(sharelink,'name','height=400,width=600');
      if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}                                                                                                                                
      return false;
    }   
   var url="www.google.com";
        googleplusbtn(url);
```

[Refer this link](http://bobbelderbos.com/2011/11/customized-google-share-button/)

Answer (score 1):

The share link is intended for native client applications, Flash applications, highly privacy-sensitive sites, and others who may not be able to use the +1 or share button. Adding the following markup to your site will include a simple icon which will pop open a share dialog for your visitors.

```html
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868291/google-plus-share-and-parameters-in-url" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
          '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
          src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very poor. You should use api for login then share content.

```
 require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('YOUR_REDIRECT_URI');
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
$visibleActions = array(
  'http://schema.org/AddAction',
  'http://schema.org/ReviewAction');

$authUrl .= '&request_visible_actions=' .
    urlencode(implode(' ', $visibleActions));
print '<a href="' . $authUrl . '">Sign in with Google</a>';
```

Comment: No. Your answer is very poor... We shouldn't be required to use an entire API from a third-party to make a simple GET request.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that `redirect_uri` is something that cannot be used without digitally signed data and shared secret. Other social media providers seem to be happy if share URL and redirect URL point to identical host+port combination (also known as "origin").